# How to send array to route store method In laravel 4.2 Or how to convert string to array

Tags: string, laravel

how to send Jquery array value to controller to store the data in Db laravel

And also how to convert string to array

Eg I will get the value like this '1|2|3|4'

Now I want to convert the string to array I want to make a for loop to store the dynamic data values into DB

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "jQuery array value". If you have an input array (e.g: ) you should simply be able to use `Input::get('foo')` which should be an array with the keys supplied in the html. So the example input above should provide

```
array(
    "bar" => "input value"
)
```

To convert a string to array you can use PHP's `explode()` function. This takes a string and splits it by a given character.

```
$array = explode('|', $string);
```

See: http://php.net/EXPLODE